# let is not defined in DrRacket

Tags: racket

I'm trying to learn `Racket` by using `DrRacket` and when run this code:

```
(define f2!
 (let ([n 0])
  (lambda()
   (set​! ​n (add1 n))
    n)))
```

I get an exception: `let: this function is not defined`.

What am I doing wrong?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a solution, I had to pick `racket` as the main language and also add:

```
#lang racket
```

at the top of the file.

Answer (score 1):

Just so you know, the #lang at the top of your file determines what set of actions you are permitted to and also the computation algorithm (Applicative/normal evaluator).

I basically add #lang racket as a basic to all files.